# Create column if the data comes from a certain table in a sql view

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a view in SQL Snowflake that is a union of two tables. The tables have the same columns, they just come from two different departments. Is there a way to create a new column that uses a case or if then to say "if data comes from this table, in the new column put Department A, (or vice versa with Department B)" and then union the data?

Comment: The answer below is spot on --- however if this your intention or are you saying that records could be blended in a UNION instead of a UNION ALL?

Answer (score 0):

Just create the new column in your view, prior to the union, and provide the values as scalar constants...

```
SELECT 'A' AS dept, * FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' AS dept, * FROM Table2
```